# About the definition of inaccessible cardinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

if $L$ satisfy the following:

1. $L$ is an uncountable cardinal
2. $L$ is a limit cardinal, i.e. $L$ is not a successor cardinal, i.e. there is no cardinal $\kappa$ such that $L$ is the least cardinal strictly bigger than $\kappa$.
3. $L$ is regular

Does that mean that $L$ must be inaccessible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uncountable regular limit cardinals are called *weakly* inaccessible. For a weakly inaccessible $\kappa$ to be inaccessible it also needs to be a strong limit, which means $2^{\lambda} < \kappa$ for all $\lambda < \kappa.$

(Note some references use the term "*strongly* inaccessible", rather than just "inaccessible", to contrast with the weak notion.)

It is consistent that every weakly inaccessible cardinal is inaccessible: If we assume GCH, then every limit is a strong limit, since $\lambda < \kappa$ implies $2^\lambda = \lambda^+ < \kappa.$

However, it is also consistent that there are weak inaccessibles that are not inaccessible. For instance, we can use Cohen forcing to move the continuum larger than the smallest weakly inaccessible $\kappa$. Cohen forcing preserves cardinals and regularity, so it preserves weak inaccessibility. Thus in the forcing extension, $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible, but it is clearly not a strong limit since $2^{\aleph_0}$ is larger.

Comment: so the definition given at the wikipedia of a weakly inaccessible as a regular limit cardinal of *regular* cardinals, is just to differentiate it from $\omega$, to quote wikipedia "An ordinal is a weakly inaccessible cardinal if and only if it is a regular ordinal and it is a limit of regular ordinals. (Zero, one, and ${\displaystyle \aleph _{0}}$ are regular ordinals, but not limits of regular ordinals.)"